# How to send iframe id/name to a php file?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have a iframe with a name, in this case an email address that changes from users.
I need to deal with this var:

```
<iframe name="asd@asd.lol" src="index.html">
```

index.html is a simple data form like this:

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<p>Upload: <input type="file" name="file1"> <br /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I need to pass the value "asd@asd.lol" to the "upload.php" file.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to add a querystring parameter into the index.html file?

So:

```
<iframe name="asd@asd.lol" src="index.html?email=asd@asd.lol">
```

Then in the index.html file set a hidden variable:

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<p>Upload: <input type="file" name="file1"> <br /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

If this is a plain HTML file you could set the value of the hidden field with some javascript.

Then use $_POST["email"] to get the email value out of the hidden field.

Comment: Ok this is the best solution.

Comment: I dunno why now is not working.
I checked the iframe and the value are passed correctly and the var is set, but with null.
The isset function in the php file returns ok, but there isn't the email address but a empty line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" onsubmit='$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="iframeEmail" value="'+$("iframe[src='index.html']").attr('name')+'">')'>
<p>Upload: <input type="file" name="file1"> <br /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Try this out ,if it wont work ,than place the iFrame and ID and find it with the ID on jQuery Selector